# Parametrized stored procedure error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express. Coins and themes are my tables. I created a stored procedures using the above two and got struck with

> Error:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure themestat, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'id2'.

Here is my whole procedure:

```
create procedure themestat(id2 In numeric, id1 In numeric)
is
   @userid nvarchar(50), @co nvarchar(50), @price nvarchar(50)
begin
   update themes set prioirty=1 where themeid=id2;
   select credits as co from coins where uid=id1;
   select rate as price from themes where priority=1;
   if(co>price)
   begin
     update themes set status=1 where priority=1;
     update themes set priority=0 where themeid=id2;
   end
   else
   begin
     update themes set priority=0 where theme=id2;
     PRINT 'no sufficient coins'
   end
end
```

I am curious to know where I went wrong ??

Comment: If you have a look at the documentation for [create procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) I am sure you will spot where you went wrong. First thing would be how to declare parameters `@parameter` but you have more issues than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you've got the syntax from, but datatypes are declared as '@param type', so the first line should read:

```
create procedure themestat 
    @id2 numeric
    @id1 numeric
```

Then obviously change all references of id1 and id2 as appropriate. There's other syntax errors in the script (missing `declare`, `is` instead of `as`, possibly others - I've not looked much closer).

This makes me wonder whether you've come from a different SQL dialect? I suggst reading about [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) on the MSDN (as well as other pages).

Comment: I just want to make sure if it's possible to pass arguments to stored procedures,like we do in functions(arg1,arg2)??

Comment: It is, but your syntax is completely wrong which is why I was wondering where you'd got that syntax from...

Comment: ye,googled it around,i made changes from is to as,'@' declarations which where missing in the code,there are no issues about it..all i am looking for is to pass variables to my stored procedures!!??any help around this would be nice :)